# Replacing text using Regex expression in Notepad ++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am trying to make the following change in a large number of files using Notepad++.

Before replacement, I have following text

```
<img src ="wsg://iDSGFQ">
<img src ="wsg://iSTACK">
<img src ="wsg://iOVERFLOW">
```

After replacement, I want to have following result

```
<img src ="http://localhost/images/DSGFQ.jpg">
<img src ="http://localhost/images/STACK.jpg">
<img src ="http://localhost/images/OVERFLOW.jpg">
```

What Regex expression can I use to convert my text ?

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what's the pattern in this replacing?

Comment: Hello jcmaad. Sorry but your question is not clear. As tiw said, what is the part that is changed, that is variable. Personally, I suppose that the string DSGFQ can be changed and all other part of FROM string are fix. I suppose that because it is not explain in your question. Can you enhance your question in giving not only on example but 2 or 3 so that we know what you will. Without other explanation, I don't see why you will use a Regex because a simple Search/Replace is enough !

Comment: Sorry for confusion, I need to replace 'wsg://' to 'http://localhost/images/[VARIABLE].jpg' in over 10K files.

DSGFQ is the variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If DSGSQ is the part that is variable in your question (see my comment below question),

a possible Regex is

Find:

```
(<img src ="wsg://i)([^"]*)(">)
```

Replace :

```
<img src ="http://localhost/images/$2.jpg">
```

Comment: @jcmaad: thank for your choice. But I know understand your problem. I will now change your question so that it is well defined as I proposed to you in my first comment (see comment in your question). Next time your write a question, try to be clear for others to avoid negative reputations.

Answer (score 0):

For your exact example, you can do this:

```
Find: (<img src =")[^"]*(">)
Replace : $1http://localhost/images/DSGFQ.jpg$2
```

Explain:

```
 - (<img src =") is Group capture to $1
 - [^"]* is the link we want to replace with
 - (">) is Group capture to $2
```

Because this is HTML, you maybe want to add more optional space like this:

```
<img   src =   "wsg://iDSGFQ"  >
```

You can replace above code with this one:

```
Find: (<img\s+src\s+=\s+")[^"]*("\s+>)
Replace : $1http://localhost/images/DSGFQ.jpg$2
```

Where \s+ is the space (more than zero space)

Answer (score 0):

You could try following pattern: `(<img.+src ?=")[^/]+\/([^"]+)`
and replacement pattern: `(\1)http:\/\/localhost\/images(\2)`.

Note that `http:\/\/localhost\/images` is harcoded. Also, (\1) means substitute first capturing group and analogically (\2) means substitute second capturing group.

Pattern explanation:

`(<img.+src ?=")` match `<img` and any characters until `src`, match `src` followed by 0 or 1 space `*`, and equal sign with double quote, store in first capturing group.

`[^/]+` - match one or more characters until `\`, them match one `\` with `\/`, finally
`([^"]+)` matches one or more characters different from double quote and stores it in second capturing group.